# selectInput box in R/shiny - choices list with same label for multiple values

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a Web App using rShiny (shiny_0.9.1) R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) and Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit). I am using the selectInput method in my ui file for selecting two columns ("IND1_WATER", "IND2_WATER") from a dataframe. 
Here is the working example code:

```
  selectInput(inputId = "indicators",
                       multiple = TRUE,
                       label = "Select the list of indicators",
                       choices = list("Water stress" = "IND1_WATER",
                                      "Water scarcity" = "IND2_WATER")
```

However I would like to label the two columns with the same name and use those for rendering a chart. I have tried different options like "Water stress" = c("IND1_WATER","IND2_WATER") or "Water stress" = colnames(mydf)[6:7] but they didn't work. It only takes the first value. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Juan

Comment: You might be talking about a feature that has not been implemented yet: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/326

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Any updates on this from the shiny community? Thanks

Comment: Good to know that. You may help increase its priority by bumping that issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Each "choice" can only have one value associated with it. If you want to have multiple values returned for a single selection, you'll have to fake it by concatenating the values you want. For example

```
selectInput(inputId = "indicators",
    multiple = TRUE,
    label = "Select the list of indicators",
    choices = list("Water stress" = "IND1_WATER,IND2_WATER")
```

And then on the server side

```
indicators <- strsplit(input$indicators, ",")[[1]]
```

Which will work if there are commas or not.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick for your prompt answer but I couldn't figure out the way to implement this. The strsplit function works only for characters but my indicators are all numeric type. I would appreciate if you have any other suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Values in an HTML select element are always character. So `input$indicators` should always be a character anyway. After the `strsplit`, you can do `as.numeric` if necessary. Otherwise, I don't understand your problem.

Comment: My first problem was the one that Yihui solved. The second problem is indeed having multiple values returned for a single selection. I have put the application on github so it is easier to share it with you. You can run the app using runGitHub('shiny-app', 'Arevaju'). My problem is in the second tab, I want users to be able to select an Ind X and display 3 values for 2010,2020 and 2050. For the time being the indicator filter doesn't really work as it only displays data for the first Indicator (Ind1). I am really stuck with this. Thanks a lot for your great support.

Comment: I noticed that there was a problem when sharing the app. The files can be seen at https://github.com/Arevaju/shiny-app.

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of **shiny** on CRAN (`>= 0.10.1`), you can use the new `optgroup` feature (see [an example here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/option-groups-for-selectize-input.html)). In your case,

```
selectInput(inputId = "indicators",
            multiple = TRUE,
            label = "Select the list of indicators",
            choices = list("Water stress" = c("IND1_WATER", "IND2_WATER")))
```

So please `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` if you have not updated your R packages.

Comment: I tried with that but it didn't work. In fact the problem is on the server side. https://github.com/Arevaju/shiny-app/blob/master/server.r. The radar chart should displayed two indicators at the time in this example IND1_WATER and IND2_WATER.

Comment: The main problem is to select two columns Ind1 and Ind2 at the same time via the interface and then use the function "Passdata2" to merge these two columns and pass it to rCharts to display the radar chart with these two indicators.Thanks!

Comment: I cannot run your app: I get an error `Error in normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE) : path[1]="": No such file or directory`. I'm not familiar with rCharts package, and I'd suggest you ask Ramnath: https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts I can only investigate the problem after I can run the app. At the moment, it is totally unclear to me what your problem really is. Sorry.

Comment: It should work now! I noticed that the highcharts library should be named all in small letters in order to work in Linux! Thanks.

Comment: @jarevalo I think that is a totally different problem with what you originally asked. Initially `input$indicators` is `NULL`, and `strsplit()` cannot split a `NULL` value. If you use what I posted as the answer, and deal with the `NULL` situation appropriately (what should you do when it is NULL?), I do not think I failed to answer your original question. For new questions, please create new posts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my last question. In order to have multiple values returned for a single selection the ui file should be something like this:

```
  selectInput(inputId = "indicator",
                label = (HTML("<b>Select a list of indicators:</b>")),
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = 'Water stress',
               choices = list("Water stress" = "Water stress", "Water scarcity" = "Water scarcity" ))
```

While the server file should include some conditional statements in order to be able to select more than one column one a particular value is selected:

```
passData <- reactive({
    data <- data[data$Country %in% input$country_filter1 & 
                   data$Year %in% input$year,]
    rownames(data) = unique(data$NUTS_CODE)
    if (input$indicator== 'Water stress') {col= 7:9}
    if (input$indicator== 'Water scarcity') {col= 8:9}
    data[,col]
  })
```

I hope it helps others with a similar problem. Thanks to my colleague Javier Martinez for his invaluable contribution!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this issue as

```r
indicators <- strsplit(input$indicators, ",")[[1]]
```

will issue a warning: "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" when used in conjunction with:

```r
filter_at(., vars(col1, col2), any_vars(. == indicators))
```

You must use:

```r
filter_at(., vars(col1, col2), any_vars(. %in% indicators))
```